# How to plot a 2-demension graph using a n*2 matrix in matlab?

Tags: matlab, matrix, plot

Now I get a matrix named Test with 1000 rows and 2 columns, which contains the (x, y) coordinates of 1000 dots. The first column is the values of X-coordinate, and the second is the values of Y-coordinate.

Now I want to display(plot) all the dots, but I found it's wrong if I just used plot(Test).

Could you guys give me a solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you want a scatter plot, which you can get by,

```
plot(Test(:,1), Test(:,2), '*')
```

You can change the marker to a number of different symbols.  For example, `'o'` gives a circle, `'*'` gives an asterisk, `'.'` gives a point, etc.  See the documents for [plot](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/plot.html) for the full list.

If you leave off the marker specification, it will default to no marker with a solid line connecting the points -- not good for a scatter plot!

Answer (score 1):

When you use the single-argument form of [plot](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/plot.html) (i.e. `plot(Y)`), when `Y` is a matrix each column of Y is plotted against the row number.

If column 1 represents `x` and column 2 is `y` you need to use the two-argument form:

```
plot(Test(:,1), Test(:,2))
```